# What is the inverse to hyperoperation for positive integers?

Tags: functions, arithmetic, inverse, recursion, hyperoperation

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) hyperoperation for positive integers is defined as
$$
H_{n}(a,b)=H_{n-1}(a,H_{n}(a,b-1))
$$
with some base conditions. (We take $ n \geqslant 1 $.)

Question:
Recursivly define a sequence of binary operators that inverts hyperoperation for all positive integers.
Meaning we are looking for $I_{n}$ such that
$$
\forall n,a,b \in \mathbb{N}_{+}: I_{n}(H_{n}(a,b),a)=b
$$

Comment: This is at most possible for $n \geq 1$, because $H_0$ ignores its first argument.

Comment: $I_{0}$ I'd simply define as counting down (by $1$).

Comment: That wouldn't work. The problem is that you are asking for an inverse of $H_n(\cdot, b)$, but $H_0$ is not injective in it's first component. Indeed, $H_0(a, b) = b+1$ for *every* $a \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, so with your definition we would have $I_0(H_0(a,b), b) = b$ for every $a \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$...

Comment: I'd rather define $H_{0}(a,b)=a+1$. Mentioned it on the discussion page... Then it would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because you'd be messing with the base case of the definition of $H_n$. Indeed, consider $H_o'(a,b) = a + 1$. Then $H_1(1,b) = H_0'(1, H_1(1, b-1)) = 2$ for every $b > 0$...

Comment: I guess I'd also define $H_{n-1}(H_{n}(a,b-1),b)$. But as I said: Things become more difficult as soon as we leave positive integers.

Comment: But we *are* dealing with non-negative integers here (this isn't related to my comment to your answer). Anyway, that definition would mess with the higher operations, e.g. $$H_2(1,2) = H_1(H_2(1,1),2) = H_1(1,2) = H_0(H_1(1,1),2) = H_0(2,2) = 3.$$What you can do, though, is simply say that $I_n$ is defined for $n > 0$. As a side note, you might enjoy reding [Proofs and Refutations](https://books.google.com/books?id=1n6SFdXCOBQC) by Imre Lakatos.

Comment: Let me note that I'm not writing "left" or "right" inverse because the other type of inverse can be introduced with H(a, 1/d) for non-natural numbers. So in that sense there is actually no need to define a second inverse operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples:

- $9/3=1+(9-3)/3=1+(1+(6-3)/3)=1+(1+1)=3$
- $log_{2}(8)=1+log_{2}(8/2) =1+(1+log_{2}(4/2))=1+(1+1)=3$
- $log_{3}(27)=1+log_{3}(27/3) =1+(1+log_{3}(9/3))=1+(1+1)=3$

So in general:
$$
I_{n}(c,a)=1+I_{n}(I_{n-1}(c,a),a)
$$
whereby $I_{n}(a,a)=1$ for $n>1$ and $I_{1}(c,a)=c-a$ for $n=1$.

Comment: This definition will terminate only when the first argument of $I_n(\cdot, b)$ is of the form $H_n(a,b)$. Can the definition be meaningfully extended to other values? For example, we might say something like $I_n(c,d) = 0$ if $d > c$, to give the "quotient" of the (pseudo)inverse, discarding the "remainder" (I didn't actually test if this is sufficient).

Comment: I have some ideas on how to expand it to other number sets or even construct new number sets from it. But it was too hard, so I restricted myself to positive integers for now.

Comment: This definition doesn't always hold true.  It only occurs here due to log rules, mainly $1+\log_b(a)=\log_b(ab)$

Comment: I claim that it holds true for all n purely from the definition of the Hyperoperator. The inverse basically counts the number of repetitions... or it should... I'm always thankful for corrections...

Comment: After some adjustments the variable names are hopefully more consistent, now.

Comment: @A.P. One option is to throw an error, where it doesn't terminate, saying the "input expression is irreducable".

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work. Even overlooking the fact that here we're working with mathematical objects and not computer programs (hence there's no way to "throw an error"), the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is undecidable. In other words, we can't know whether a computation will terminate or not without actually running the whole computation; but then if it doesn't appear to terminate is it just because it's too soon and it actually takes a very long time to finish? And if not, how do we throw an error, since we're stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: In this case, we could see whether it terminates without waiting. We can simply check whether the first parameter has become smaller than the second parameter. Then the algorithm defining the inverse hyperoperation function should go into the 'irreducable' case. That means the function maps on the original expression as a 'number'.